# create-react-app and react-router routes not working correctly in S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-router

I've built my app with npm run build and am uploading the build to S3 but can't get the routes quite right.

The routes work in development but stop once built and uploaded.  I can also serve it locally no problem but on S3 it stops.

Here's what's working locally

```
<Route path="/" exact component={HomeView} />
<Route path="/home" component={HomeView} />
```

The only way I can get it to (sort of) work in S3 is by using /*

```
<Route path="/" exact component={HomeView} />
<Route path="/*" exact component={HomeView} />
<Route path="/home" component={HomeView} />
```

The problem with /* is that every route also has the homepage above it.  So both routes are stacked on top of each other.  With the first setup though, nothing is displayed and if I inspect the page, the root element is empty.  Index.js still loads because the background changes color according to the styles it loads.  It just seems that react-router isn't getting a proper route.

The S3 bucket is setup to point at index.html.  I'm sure the problem is probably fairly simple to fix but it's my misunderstanding of react-router that's getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working after trying many things:

```
<Route path="/*" component={() => <Redirect to='/home' />} />
```

A new problem though is that you land on index.html which redirects your url to www.mydomain.com/home and everything looks good.  But if you give that link to someone, they get an error.  I.e. if I copy the url and paste it into a new tab, I'll get an error.  It only seems to work if you *first* navigate to www.mydomain.com/index.html and let react-router take over.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem by using `HashRouter`.

```
import { Switch, Route, HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => (
    <HashRouter>
        <div>
            <NavBar/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projects}/>
                <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
                <Route component={NoMatch}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </HashRouter>
);
```

The app is accessible by something like
`https://your-domain.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?someParam=foo&otherPram=bar/#/projects`

on localhost like
`https://localhost:3000/?someParam=foo&otherPram=bar/#/projects`

No changes in S3 were needed.